# Find the numbers that are multiples of 3 between 100 and 40

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

As the title says , i have to fin the multiples of  that appear between the numbers 40 and 100. I have to use for

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <conio.h>

   int main()
    {
     int n=3;
     int i=100;
     for(i=100;i>=40;i--)

         printf(" %d ",n*n);
     getch();
     return 0;
    }
```

That is what I've got. But it only prints the number 9 a lot of times. How do i fix it so it that it prints out all the multiples of 3?

Comment: It prints the number 49? It should print 9 a lot of times, because you print `n*n` in the loop and never change the value of `n`. You also want to learn about the meaning of multiple - it's not always a square number.

Comment: How it print `49`? your `printf` is wrong first check `        `if(i%3==0)` then `printf(" %d ",i);`.

Comment: I mistyped the number. Is that my head can't wrap how to do the problem, and I've been having troubles making it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int n=3;
for(int i=100; i>=40; i--)
{
    if(i%n == 0 )
        printf("%d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you printing n*n? n is always 3 and n*n is always 9. Therefore 9 always gets printed. What you want to do is go through all numbers between 40 and 100, check IF the number is divisible by 3, and then print it. The % operator gives you the remainder when you divide something, so IF the remainder is 0 when divided by 3, it means the number is divisible by 3. This is how you would proceed:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <conio.h>

   int main()
   {
       //int n=3;Don't need n=3, we will simply use 3 itself.
       int i;    //Not needed to initialize to 100 here, you are initializing in loop anyway.  
       for(i=100;i>=40;i--)
       {
           if( i%3 == 0)
               printf("%d\n", i);   
       }


       getch();
       return 0;
   }
```

The above will print numbers in reverse starting from 99 and ending with 42. If youw ant the other way around, simply initialize i to 40 instead of 100, and have loop condition i<=100 and increment i each iteration.

Another simpler solution can be this, since we know the first multiple of 3 between 40 and 100 is 42,:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=42;
    while(i<=100)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i+=3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here we simply print 42, then add 3 and print , and repeat till `i` is greater than 100, i.e., it will print 42,45,48.... go on adding 3.... 99 and then when it gets to 102, it is greater than 100 so it will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

use `mod` instead, use it to determine if number is divisable by 3 , in your case `n = 3;` but you can use the same approach to find multiples of any number

```
#include <stdio.h>
  #include <conio.h>

   int main()
    {
     int n=3;
     int i=100;
     for(i=100;i>=40;i--)

      if ((i % n) == 0)   printf(" %d ",i);
     getch();
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @jtman though i prefer `UpVote` &| `accepted answer` rather :)